# Optimus: load-assets not working with Regex

Tags: build, clojure, classpath

I'm trying to build a static site with [stasis](https://github.com/magnars/stasis) and serve my assets with [Optimus](https://github.com/magnars/optimus). Pictures reside under /resources/public/imgs/ . I can serve individual pictures after loading them as follows:

```
(optimus.assets/load-assets "public"
                            ["/imgs/pic1.jpg"
                             "/imgs/pic2.jpg"])
```

The following attempt to serve pictures by regex does not work though:

```
(optimus.assets/load-assets "public"
                            [#"/imgs/.*\.jpg"])
```

I'm getting `No files matched regex /imgs/.*\.jpg`, which seems implausible.

I've done some digging around the Optimus code and may have found the culprit. When called with a regex the `optimus.assets/load-assets` function starts building the paths from the return value of `(optimus.class-path/file-paths-on-class-path)`, which – in my case – consists of only the following:

```
optimus.class-path/file-paths-on-class-path
=> ("boot/" "boot/tag-release.properties" "boot/bin/" "boot/bin/ParentClassLoader.class" "Boot.class" "META-INF/" "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
```

Since `resources` isn't a subdir of any of these directories I'm not surprised that I don't get a match. So maybe my question ultimately is why I'm getting only these directories here? Is it because I'm using Boot rather than Leiningen which is presupposed by the tutorials on Optimus?

EDIT:

It has definitely something to do with Boot or at least the way I've set it up. Following Alan Thompson's advice I've created a minimal Leiningen project – `load-assets` worked flawlessly. The very same setup with Boot however does not. Ultimately it boils down to `(System/getProperty "java.class.path" ".")` returning wildly different things: Boot gives me `"/home/phylax/bin/boot"`, i.e. my boot binary, whereas in Leiningen it gives me a plethora of directories in my actual project… any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? How can I setup Boot to work with Optimus?

Many thanks for any guidance you may give me on this

Oliver

Comment: When in doubt, first repro the known facts (i.e. the tutorial) as it exists. Then do small mods, incrementally, in the direction of your goal. That works for pretty much anything.  Usually, it is the only way that does.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually done that now  by using Leiningen for a minimal example that works. There is, however, no way to incrementally switch to another build tool… and switching to Boot breaks that minimal example… I've put more details into the actual question.